# What is the correct way of solving npm dependency tree errors?

Tags: node.js, npm, nestjs, node-modules, npm-install

After running `npx npm-check-updates -u` I tried running `npm install`, and got the following message:

```
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Found: @nestjs/typeorm@8.0.3
npm ERR! node_modules/@nestjs/typeorm
npm ERR!   @nestjs/typeorm@"^8.1.4" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! @nestjs/typeorm@"^8.1.4" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: typeorm@0.3.6
npm ERR! node_modules/typeorm
npm ERR!   peer typeorm@"^0.3.0" from @nestjs/typeorm@8.1.4
npm ERR!   node_modules/@nestjs/typeorm
npm ERR!     @nestjs/typeorm@"^8.1.4" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

I've searched and seen people recommend just using `--legacy-peer-deps` or `--force`, but is it supposed to be solved that way? Or am I supposed to manually fix the issue?

I tried searching for guides on how to resolve dependency tree errors but couldn't find any. Could you give me some guidance on where should I start with resolving the errors.

Comment: Did you find a solution? The @nestjs/typeorm started to use 0.3 version since [8.1.0](https://github.com/nestjs/typeorm/releases/tag/8.1.0), so it should work but it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [discussion](https://github.com/nestjs/typeorm/issues/1289#issuecomment-1144561626) about the issue with incompatible versions between `nestjs/typeorm` and `typeorm`. if you want to keep use the old version, try to use the fix version with:

```
"@nestjs/typeorm": "8.0.4",
"typeorm": "0.2.40",
```

Reinstall the packages, and it should fix the issue.

Comment: good job, good luck

Answer (score -1):

i fixed it by do following steps:

- restart computer
- delete and clone project again
- npm i again and anything is good

Comment: This would not answer the question topic started asked. your package json stays the same and it defines the packages versions installed